# How do I make my desired font be the default font in the memoir class?

Tags: fonts, memoir

I was confused by reading something regarding this topic in the `memoir` documentation. Can't I just load the package directly so that it can be the default font in my document?

Comment: What is this "something"?

Comment: Chapter 1.2.1: Extended font sizes, page 3.

Comment: Regarding my edit: [Why is “thanks” inappropriate at the end of a question?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/2809/5764); [Removing “thanks” from questions](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/3602/5764). Of course, it's personal preference.

Comment: It depends on the font. Which font do you want to use? BTW: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Comment: Haha, I get it now why did you do that edit. Thanks @Werner! @karlkoeller, I would want to use Bitstream Charter. Thanks! Also, how can I produce a line break in a comment box?

Answer (score 1):

Of course, but as karlkoeller said, it depend of the font. See [The LaTeX Font Catalogue](http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/).

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{times} % change by times,bookman,palatino, etc.
\renewcommand*\familydefault{\sfdefault} % if the base font is sans serif
\usepackage{blindtext} % for dummy text
\begin{document}
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please don't use times. It does not bring propper math fonts. Why do you need the sf line? Is the entire document in sf?

Comment: @daleif, Yes for example `mathptmx` or `txfonts` is better, no doubt. The sf line is only to show how to do, only "if" the base font will be serif, as I do not know what Acnologia want to do exactly.

Comment: Contrary to popular belief, not all TeX users are mathematicians or people who include math in their work. So there's nothing wrong with using ``times``.

Comment: @Sverre I'd say the contrary: `times` is obsolete and `mathptmx` or `newtxtext` (along with `newtxmath`) should be used. Or else `tgtermes`.

Comment: @egreg I actually thought ``times`` was just a wrap for ``tgtermes``, but I see now it's not. But anyway, my point was to take issue with the principle that we have to avoid fonts that aren't well suited for math, since many of us don't include math anyway.

Comment: @Sverre, I understand perfectly your perspective (I am not a mathematician), but most users here (not all) use maths, so in general another font is better. BTW, this was only a example, not a recommendation. Really I never use `times` or similar fonts (too narrow for my taste even in two columns). To recommend one, I would say `palatino`... well, with the permission of mathematicians, I meant `mathpazo`.

Comment: Thanks guys, but @Fran, am I correct in saying that I should know what type of font in the font family I should use? So, in my case, if I want to use Bitstream Charter font family, I must check if the style I want is serif or sans-serif? Also (sorry for these piled follow-up questions), if I would want the serif font I need not to renew any commands?

Comment: @Acnologia In many font packages the serif font is the default, for example in `\usepackage[bitstream-charter]{mathdesign}` so if you want all your document in sans serif often you need to redefine the `\familydefault`. Some times this is simpliied with a package option. But there are also packages only with sans serif  fonts, so you don't need change anything. For example  `\usepackage{iwona}` is enough to obtain a sans serif.